# How to avoid this voltage when I turn on the circuit?

Tags: switches, timer, 555, delay

What I want to do is an Delay ON, but when I press the switch this voltage pass for a brief moment and turns the led on for a moment[image].

- How can I avoid this?
- Should I put the switch somewhere else?

If you can make another suggestion for a circuit I wold be happy to read it, what I need is that the led  come on only  if the switch is on continously for more than 13 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this circuit to your reset pin so it ignores random turn-on pulses. It delays any turn-on pulse by about 100 milliseconds. The time delay is ~\$1.1{\cdot}R{\cdot}C\$. D1 is used to make sure of a fast reset when power is OFF. To increase time delay increase R1 instead of C1. High values of C1 could damage D1 when power is switched OFF. Multiply R1 by 10 to get 10 times the delay, etc.

NOTE: I noticed in your diagram you had no bypass capacitors for the IC. It is **mandatory** to have bypass capacitors close to the IC so it is stable. C2 should be right at the power and ground pins of the IC. The 100 uF capacitor should be within 2 inch's/50mm of the IC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnj7B2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>